# Spring AWS: Access denied error when deploying war on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm seeing the below error when deploying war with Spring AWS on AWS EB:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'embeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.annotation.ProxyCachingConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: void org.springframework.cache.annotation.AbstractCachingConfiguration.setConfigurers(java.util.Collection);
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.aws.cache.config.annotation.ElastiCacheCachingConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.env.stack.ListableStackResourceFactory org.springframework.cloud.aws.cache.config.annotation.ElastiCacheCachingConfiguration.stackResourceFactory;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/aws/autoconfigure/context/ContextStackAutoConfiguration$StackAutoDetectConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.env.stack.config.StackResourceRegistryFactoryBean]: Factory method 'stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean' threw exception;
nested exception is com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: User: arn:aws:sts::<id>:assumed-role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role/<id> is not authorized to perform: cloudformation:DescribeStackResources (Service: AmazonCloudFormation; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: <request-id>)
```

The username shown is apparently a temp user created during the process.
Not sure what all info I need to provide -- please let me know, and I shall add.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was apparently due to a problem in the spring config file. Some xsd URLs where invalid, and so the aws credentials provided weren't being used.
Fixing the URLs fixed the issue.